Implement EIP 712 signature generation in nodejs not working
I have a contract I am trying to make a call to this function in a contract,
    function executeAction(
        address to,
        uint256 value,
        bytes calldata data,
        uint256 _nonce,
        Types.ReimburseGas calldata gasParams, // Use Types.ReimburseGas
        bytes calldata signature
    ) external payable onlyRelayer onlyAllowedContract(to) nonReentrant {
        // Record the initial gas
        uint256 initialGas = gasleft();
        address signer = signerRegistry.getSigner(clientId);

        // Validate nonce
        require(_nonce == nonce, "Invalid nonce");
        nonce++;

        // Verify the user's signature
        bytes32 messageHash = getMessageHash(to, value, data, _nonce, gasParams);
        require(
            verifySignature(signer, messageHash, signature),
            "Invalid signature"
        );

        // Execute the action
        (bool success, ) = to.call{value: value}(data);
        require(success, "Action execution failed");

        emit ActionExecuted(to, value, data);
    }

I have also implement the unit test for this in forge which has a helper function for generating the signature.
    /// @notice Helper function to generate EIP-712 signature
    function _signExecuteAction(
        address to,
        uint256 value,
        bytes memory data,
        uint256 _nonce,
        Types.ReimburseGas memory gasParams
    ) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        // Compute the message hash
        bytes32 gasStructHash = keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                wallet.REIMBURSE_GAS_TYPEHASH(),
                gasParams.gasPrice,
                gasParams.gasLimit,
                gasParams.reimburse,
                gasParams.reimburseInNative,
                gasParams.tokenRate,
                gasParams.token
            )
        );

        bytes32 structHash = keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                wallet.EXECUTE_ACTION_TYPEHASH(),
                to,
                value,
                keccak256(data),
                _nonce,
                gasStructHash
            )
        );

        bytes32 digest = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked("\x19\x01", wallet.DOMAIN_SEPARATOR(), structHash)
        );

        // Sign the digest using the signer's private key
        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = vm.sign(signerPrivateKey, digest);
        return abi.encodePacked(r, s, v);
    }

I am having difficulty implementing this in nodejs with viem, it keeps throwing a "Invalid signature" error. Here is my code so far.
export async function generateSignature(
  clientId: Hex,
  userId: Hex,
  action: Action,
): Promise<{ userWalletAddress: Hex; signature: Hex }> {
  try {
    const userWalletAddress = await getUserWalletContract(clientId, userId)
    action.nonce = await publicClient.readContract({
      address: userWalletAddress,
      abi: userWalletAbi,
      functionName: 'nonce',
    })

    const signature = await signerClient.signTypedData({
      domain: {
        name: 'Wallet',
        chainId: chainId,
        verifyingContract: userWalletAddress,
      },
      types,
      message: {
        to: action.to,
        value: action.value,
        data: keccak256(action.data),
        nonce: action.nonce,
        gasParams: action.gasParams,
      },
      primaryType: 'ExecuteAction',
    })

    console.log('Signature:', signature)
    return { userWalletAddress, signature }
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('Error generating signature:', error.message || error)
    throw error
  }
}

